# Google Website Translator Breaking Search

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, google-translate

It changes all the text as it should to the language of the browser, including the search options in the dropdowns

So when a search is made for some reason the search function uses the translated word from the dropdown options so they end up on a 404 page. Is there a way to stop translated search options effecting the URL?

We are using Salesforce's Visualforce / force.com

Eg.

Correct URL for a Search (example.com/search?dropdown1=answer&dropdown2=secondanswer)

Incorrect URL for a Search (example.com/search?dropdown1=(answer in language of the browser)&dropdown2=(secondanswer in language of the browser))

Comment: Do you have a few more details. Is this a Visualforce page passing data to google translator? What is the code in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue was resolve over on the Salesforce Stack - `<span class="notranslate">` {content to not translate} `</span>`fixed the issue when I wrapped it around elements I didn't want translated

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104586/visualforce-google-website-translator-breaking-search/104596#104596